# how to Iterate Hashmap and make combinations with other keys in the same Hashmap to compare their objects

Tags: java

How to Iterate Hashmap and make combinations with other keys in the same Hashmap to compare their objects

```
Map<String, Batch> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Batch>();
map.put(A,batch1);
map.put(B,batch2);
map.put(C,batch3);
map.put(D,batch4);
```

My requirement is to iterate above hashmap and make forward combinations with other keys in the same hashmap and compare their objects, combinations mentioned below.
    AB, AC, AD, ABC, ABD, ACD, ABCD,
    BC, BD, BCD,
    CD

I tried below approach but I am able to get combinations for two item sets (AB, AC, AD, BC, BD and CD)

created duplicate hashmap with same values 
    Map mapDuplicate = new LinkedHashMap();

```
for (String item : map.keySet()){
 for (String item2 : mapDuplicate.keySet()){
 if(item != item2){
        compare batches and do stuff...............
    }
   }    
    mapDuplicate.remove(item);
 }
```

Please suggest better solution/algorithm/reference to handle above scenario ?

Comment: I'd probably look towards recursion for that if I were you.

Comment: Do you want combination like this too ABCD BC ? Then it will be infinite combination i guess .

Comment: @Mak comma was missing  between ABCD and BC , so just updated that. Thank you . I want all possible combinations in forward direction and possible combinations for above example are AB, AC, AD, ABC, ABD, ACD, ABCD, BC, BD, BCD, CD.

Comment: is your problem how to generate the  combination from a list `A,B,C,D`? @KrishnaTanniru does the order of the combinations matter? E.g. `AB, ABC, ABCD, AC, ACD, AD....` is this ok?

Comment: @kent any order is fine and I should able to compare the values of those keys in that combination.

Comment: @KrishnaTanniru ok, I am gonna add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your comment under your question, I think your problem is generating those combinations. The order you can handle in later steps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    static List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result.addAll(restList(list.get(i), list.subList(i + 1, list.size())));
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    static List<String> restList(String input, List<String> inputList) {
        List<String> restList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++) {
            String x = input + inputList.get(i);
            restList.add(x);
            restList.addAll(restList(x, inputList.subList(i + 1, inputList.size())));
        }
        return restList;
    }
}
```

If you run the above codes, you will get a list with elements:

```
[AB, ABC, ABCD, ABD, AC, ACD, AD, BC, BCD, BD, CD]
```